# Excel formula from VBA difficulty

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a formula that I want to generate in VBA and put in a cell.  The final formula is:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(B6670,ProcMIRs!B1:B235,0)),"","Found in ProcMIRs row " & MATCH(B6670,ProcMIRs!B1:B235,0))
```

and when I type this into a cell, it works fine, returning the message or nothing.

In VBA, I have:

```
rToMIRs.Offset(0, 18).Formula = "=IF(ISNA(MATCH(RC[-17],ProcMIRs!B1:B" & Sheets("ProcMIRs").Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row & ",0)),"""",""Found in ProcMIRs row "" & MATCH(RC[-17],ProcMIRs!B1:B" & Sheets("ProcMIRs").Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row & ",0))"
```

When I pop up the string in the immediate window, it's exactly what I want, but when I assign it to the worksheet, I get:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(B6673,ProcMIRs!'B1':'B235',0)),"","Found in ProcMIRs row " & MATCH(B6673,ProcMIRs!'B1':'B235',0))
```

So what the heck is inserting the single quotes around the `B1:B235` range on the ProcMIRs sheet refrence?  If I delete them in the cell, the formula operates normally, of course.  I've spent the past 30 minutes trying things like assigning it to a string variable first, etc. with no luck.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you attempted .FormulaR1C1 instead of .Formula?

Answer (score 2):

Your formula is inconsistent, you use the R1C1 markup in one place, then you switch to A1 in another. Pick one, and stick with it.

```
rToMIRs.Offset(0, 18).FormulaR1C1 = _ 
 "=IF(ISNA(MATCH(RC[-17],ProcMIRs!R1C2:R" & Sheets("ProcMIRs").Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row & _
 "C2,0)),"""",""Found in ProcMIRs row "" & MATCH(RC[-17],ProcMIRs!R1C2:R" & _
 Sheets("ProcMIRs").Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row & "C2,0))"
```

(**Untested**, I don't have Excel in front of me right now, sorry.)

Comment: It was the mix that was killing it.  Took out the R1C1 format and calculated the cell address for the formula and it worked correctly.  Thanks guys.

Comment: @BillR It's nice to tick the answer if it solves your problem